# Change size of the icon in ObjectListItem

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

i'm setting up a list by getting items from the OData service and when i want to display them using the ObjectListItem i found no way to increase the size of image and i've tried to use css like that but i didn't work

```
.sapMImg {
font-size: 400px ; /*!important;*/
}

 <ObjectListItem
                    type="Navigation"
                    press=".onSelectionChange"
                    icon="/H31{MimeType}"
                    title="{MatlDesc}"
                    number="{PriceUnit}"
                    numberUnit="{BaseUom}"
                    numberState="{= 11 > 10 ? 'Success' : 'Error' }"
                    
                    class="sapMImg"
                    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to a css file you are already using:

```
.sapUiIcon {
    font-size: 1.5rem !important;
}
```

To use an external css file, you can load them using this config on the manifest:

```
"resources": {
            "css": [
                {
                    "uri": "content/css/style.css"
                },
```

Comment: Did you check the devtools? Can you see if the css was applied?